# Yii framework. Can't save model

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have problem with Yii. I have following code in controller:

```
...
$user = User::model()->find("user_id = :id AND type='1'", array('id'=>$user->id));
$user->time=new CDbExpression('NOW()'); 
$user->status=1;
$user->save();
...
```

And Im getting this error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is to classic to knwo exactly what went wrong! here's a problem that could be the reason of your error:

When you find your user, if it doesn't find it the method will return `false` then the rest of the operations will fail. You should perform something like:

```
$user = User::model()->find("user_id = :id AND type='1'", array('id'=>$user->id));
if($user !== null) {
    $user->time=new CDbExpression('NOW()'); 
    $user->status=1;
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Still im getting error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: could you do a var_dump of $user after the if condition and show us the result?

Comment: `object(stdClass)#158 (2) {
  ["time"]=>
  object(CDbExpression)#159 (4) {
    ["expression"]=>
    string(5) "NOW()"
    ["params"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["status"]=>
  int(1)
}`

Comment: Does User model has it's own find() method? I'm thinking that User model has find() method which overrides CActiveRecord's find() method and returns not what CActiveRecord::find() usually returns.

Comment: Your dump is really small, it's like the object return is not a CActiveRecord object. as @andrzej1_1 said, did you override the find method in your model?

Comment: I don't modified model. But now code works, although I don't change antything!

Comment: @darkheir Your answer is not quite right: `find()` will return `null`, not `false` if no record is found.

Comment: You're right, I written that by memory, should have checked first!

Answer (score 3):

oo i see you need to test if you have a user
just do :

```
if($user)
```

is your model extand a CactiveRecord ?

you should display the errors to know what's wrong

```
if(!$user->save()){
   var_dump($user->getErrors());
}
```

this will be helpfull

Comment: Still im getting error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: I was getting validation errors like: `Timestamp cannot be blank.`, I would have thought that these errors would have been fatal.

Answer (score 0):

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

```
        $model->startDate = $modifiedStartDate;
        $model->timeFrom = $modifiedFromTime;
        $model->timeTo = $modifiedToTime;
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($model);exit;
        $model->save();
        //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        return $this->redirect(['timelog/index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create',
                        [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

//why the error occurs while using the $method->save(); function.